# Using Boolean modifier causes cube to wrap around other cube

Tags: boolean-modifier

When I try to cut *Cube1* with *Cube2* using [`Boolean Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) difference, *Cube2* wraps around *Cube1*.

[image]

Comment: Looks like "Z Fighting" If you simply hide cube 1 does it go away?

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately it doesnt work. Also I have the same problem with 1 wall. I try using boolean for makieng a hole for a window in a wall. and the same thing happens. There are 3 meshes to go through and it works with the first one and then it wraps around 2nd and 3rd. I have no clue whats going on.

Comment: Can you modify your question and add your .blend file please? I'll have a look at it for you if you want. You can share your .blend file here https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It's like i want to put a sink in the kitchen furniture and i need to go through table top and a cabinet "top". So when i use boolean to "cut through" these 2 models the mesh kinda wraps around sink. I cant upload .blend becouse the file is already 260MB+ and its only max 30MB that can be shared. I hope now my explanations is more understandable :)

Comment: If you start a new .blend and simply have 2 cubes, does it work? If so, try and figure out what is different with your main model and fix it. For example, is the "cabinet top" manifold? See this for an understanding if you need to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBPEtHTAXcY&t=406s&ab_channel=JoshGambrell

Comment: I gave up and created totally new models. Whats strange about that. I didnt it exactly the same and it worked. Maybe someday I will find answer for that. Anyway BIG Thanks for your efforts!